# Server shutting down when exiting iTerminal

Tags: amazon-ec2, iterm2

I have an app called iTerminal on my iphone. I SSH into my amazon instance and start the server and it works great (It's a .jar file). However, the moment I exit the iTerminal app the server shuts down. What gives?! I thought the server is suppose to be running! The only way my server can shut down is if I issue an exit command. This does not make sense.

Comment: This also happens with Terminal on Mac. How do i stop the server/file from stopping running when my terminal istance closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to detach the server process from your shell. Your server is a child process of the shell and the system terminates the shell's children when the shell exits.

One way to do this is is using `nohup` and running the process in the background from the shell like this:

`nohup /your/server/command &`

`nohup` becomes the child process and, as its name suggests, it will ignore the hangup (HUP) signal that is normally sent to a child process.

The `&` runs the command in the background so you get a shell prompt back. When you exit the shell the service should still be running as an independent process.

Answer (score 1):

I found out:

Just type 'screen'
then run your server/command.

Now when you exit terminals, it doesn't kill the app.

Comment: While this will work, `screen` is a full blown window manager and is something of an overkill for just detaching a process. I'd suggest the `nohup` solution I mentioned is more appropriate.